# How to make a variable update work in riot js

Tags: data-binding, closures, riot.js

Loving riot js but why is "Hello 0" not incrementing on the page in the following code example, and what is the workaround for now?

```
<my-app>
    <p>Hello {myNumber}</p>
    this.myNumber = 0;
    var thisApp = this;
    setInterval(
        function(){
            thisApp.myNumber++;
        },
        1000
    );
</my-app>
```

Answer (score 10):

Inside the function add

```
thisApp.update();
```

There is no way to add and configure dirty checking in riot js, as of version 2.2.2-beta.

You don't need to call `update()` in the execution of your

1. outermost script
2. event functions executed via riot js html template expressions

...because riot js automatically calls `update()` after executing those.